# size a steel beam

Tags: flooring

What size beam do I need to span 21'.
Beam supported at both ends.
Beam resting and attached on concrete wall at both ends.
Beam will hold one end of a floor system - so stabilized by floor system.
Floor system rests on concrete wall at one end and on the beam at the other.  No support along the sides of the floor.
Uniform load of 8000# so the beam will need to hold 4000#.
Static loan - will be used for storage.

Comment: You need to get a structural engineer to do this, not rely on some unspecified website... if it goes wrong the insurance will hang you out to dry.

Comment: While I agree that before you actually purchase anything you'll want to have a registered engineer approve and stamp your plans.  In fact, that may be necessary in order to obtain a permit.  But it may be useful to calculate the needed beam size for planning and budgetary purposes.  I don't, however, see that you've provided enough information.  First of all, is the load 8000# or 4000#?  You seem to indicate both.  Second, what is the maximum deflection you can tolerate?  It's common that the deflection drives the design more so than the max. load capacity.

Comment: Voting to close. The question may seem simple, but probably isn't, and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

Use a A992-50 W10x19 steel beam. By saying it's a 8000# uniform load over 21 feet, the OP is telling us that it's 381# per lineal foot. 381# multiplied by 10.5 feet is 4000#, that's why he said there's 4000# at each end. This beam will deflect L/384, or about 0.66" at max deflection, which is on par for anything that spans 21'. Code minimum is L/240, so it's above that too. No, you don't need an engineer. An inspector might want a calc, so ask your lumber yard or steel beam supplier if they won't let you start without one.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Using a W10x19 seems grossly over sized. It supports a uniform load of 19,700 lbs.  It would be nice to have the OP clarify the 8,000# and 4000# issues. Dotes thinks it’s 8000# uniformly distributed over the 21’, but it could be 8000# per foot. Nowhere does the OP say the reaction is 4000# at each end. The OP just says the BEAM will need to hold 4000#. That could be a point load. (The beam doesn’t “hold a reaction. ) At 381# plf contributing to load, the floor span can only be about 3’, because storage requires a minimum of 100 psf by Code.